# How to remove conflicting return type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am dividing string and and storing it in `splitArray` and want to return it.

But I am getting conflicting `array` on the first line

```
- (NSArray *)subdividingString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *splitArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    return splitArray;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: The error comes from somewhere else. The code is ok.

Comment: but i am getting conflicting return type warning

Comment: What's the point of this method ? *componentsSeparatedByString:* does the exact same thing as *subdividingString:*

Comment: I think that you have an issue with using this function, do you use it as NSString *splitString = [self subdividingString:someString]; ?

Answer (score 1):

First: there is nothing wrong with the code, but you are most likely having another issue (e.g. where you call `subdividingString:`).

Second: You shouldn't introduce a method that is exactly doing what another one is doing already. Just use

```
NSString *mystring = @"some string";
NSArray *chunks = [mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```